# Checking if a number is a perfect square (without Math)

Tags: java, algorithm

I typed this up quickly as an intuitive solution for determining if a given number is a perfect square.

How could I improve this? I already know that it doesn't handle the case where the number is 1. I'm wondering if I could generalize the calculation so it rounds up. What can I look into to develop a mindset for tackling these sorts of problems?

```
int number = 1000000;
int half = (number + 2 - 1)/2;
int square = 0;
boolean isSquare = false;

for( int i = half; i > 0 ; i-- ){

    square = i*i;

    if( square > number )
        continue;

    if( square == number ){
        System.out.println( "This number is a perfect square" );
        isSquare = true;
        break;
    } 

}

if( !isSquare ){
    System.out.println( "This number is not a perfect square" );
}
```

Comment: try FIPS 186-3 Appendix C section 4 http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf

Comment: here's a method that can check if an integer is a perfect square using only elementary math. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226869/how-well-does-this-method-of-checking-if-an-integer-n-is-a-square-perform?noredirect=1#comment8784477_4226869

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make use of the fact that *n*² = the sum of the first *n* odd numbers (for integral *n* ≥ 0), rather than having to compute `i * i` every time through the loop.

Comment: Interesting number set property. Didn't know about that one. Thanks.

Comment: Is two additions cheaper than a multiplication?

Comment: Did the experiment, was twice as fast...

Comment: The property derives from (n+1)² - n² = 2n + 1, the next greater odd number.

Answer (score 4):

You can narrow down your search range. If a number requires `n` bits to represent, its square root is between `1 << ((n-1) / 2)` and `1 << ((n+1) / 2)`. You can determine number of bits with something like:

```
int numBits(long l) {
  for (int i = 62; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (l & (1 << i)) return i + 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I had an error in the shift statements, which I've now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

There are significant improvements that can be made by choosing a more optimal algorithm.

Better algorithms for finding the root of *x² - n = 0* are :

- Halving intervals to search for the root. This is called the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method).
- Even faster would be [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) : follow the tangent line on your current approximated root, to find a closer approximation.

Note the pseudo code on the linked wiki pages.

Both are defined to use reals, but can easily be adapted to accept only integer results : once improvements stop or are less than the distance to the nearest integer, you either have found an exact integer result, or the root isn't an integer.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to use integer square root algorithm and verify that the root's square value is the original number (e.g. x == isqrt(x)^2).

You can find integer square root algorithm code here:
http://medialab.freaknet.org/martin/src/sqrt/